# What is the right tense for this?

Tags: tense

Kids Woke up late and dad **had or has?** hangover from last night.

Question. What tense should I use? HAD or Has for this sentence. Thanks

Comment: This case is ambiguous - it could go either way, depending on the rest of the text. Can you give us some more context?

Comment: "Has a hangover" or "had a hangover"...and yes, either might work, depending on the rest of the context.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the state of the dad at the time of writing.

- If you are saying he **was** hung-over when the kids woke up, say:

  > (The) kids woke up late, and dad **had** a hangover from last night.

  - This conveys that the hangover was completed in the past.
- If you are saying he **is** hung-over, say:

  > (The) kids woke up late, and dad **has** a hangover from last night.

  - This conveys that the hangover is ongoing.

Since these are separate clauses, they don't have to agree in tense.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite vague. I think you should emphasis more, but based on how I understood it, both could be correct. Again it's based on the case.

The kids woke up late and dad has a hangover from last night. (if his hungover is current)

The kids woke up late and dad had a hangover from last night. (if his hangover period was over)